# Mock boto3 calls for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, mocking

We have a class which looks like this:

```
import boto3
import json
import time
import sys

def stop_instances_python(instanceId):
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    while True:
        try:
            ec2_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceId])
            print "EC2 instance: " + instanceId + " stopped"
            break
        except Exception, e:
            if ('RequestLimitExceeded' in str(e)):
                print "Request throttled. Sleeping for 15s"
                time.sleep(15)
                res = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceId])
                print "instance state: " + res['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['State']['Name']
                try:
                    ec2_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instanceId])
                    print "EC2 instance: " + instanceId + " stopped" ## Unable to test this
                except Exception, e:
                    if ('RequestLimitExceeded' in str(e)):
                        print "Request throttled again. Sleeping for 10s"
                        time.sleep(10)
                    else:
                        print str(e)
                        sys.exit(1)
            else:
                print str(e)
                sys.exit(1)
```

We want to write unit test cases for this class. We used `moto` and `mock` to test most of the lines. We are unable to test the line with comment: `# Unable to test this`. This is because every time stop request is sent, it is getting throttled. Our test case file looks as below:

```
from moto import mock_ec2
from moto import mock_sts
from mock import patch
import botocore
import boto3
import mock
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

orig = botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call

def mock_throttling(self, operation_name, kwarg):
    if operation_name == 'StopInstances':
        parsed_response = {
            'Error': {'Code': '500', 'Message': 'RequestLimitExceeded'}}
        raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
    return orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)

def mock_throttling_side_effect(self, operation_name, kwarg):
    mock_api = mock.Mock()
    parsed_response = {'Error': {'Code': '500', 'Message': 'RequestLimitExceeded'}}
    if operation_name == 'StopInstances':
        mock_api.side_effect = [
            ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name),
            orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)
        ]
        mock_api()       
    return orig(self, operation_name, kwarg)

class TestEC2StopInstances:
    @mock_ec2
    @mock_sts
    @patch('time.sleep', return_value=None)
    def test_ec2_lambda_handler(self, patched_time_sleep):
        from StopInstancesPython import stop_instances_python
        client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
        response = client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-1234567', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
        instanceId = response['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
        with patch(
                'botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call',
                new=mock_throttling_side_effect):
            stop_instances_python(instanceId)
```

We tried using both `mock_throttling` and `mock_throttling_side_effect`. When we use `mock_throttling`, the `StopInstances` API always throws RequestLimitExceeded exception (which is the expected behavior).
When we use `mock_throttling_side_effect`, the instance gets stopped in the first `StopInstances` API call and also throws the RequestLimitExceeded exception and continues in the infinite loop.

Could someone guide us on how to test all lines of this code?

Comment: You guys are reinventing the wheel.  Use [`botocore.stub`](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/stubber.html) and your lives will get much easier.

Comment: @wim No. Stubber doesn't work for various AWS services in a CI environment due to the `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.` error, even if it does work for S3. [This](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2485#issuecomment-752454137) is the only service-agnostic workaround.